# missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, wpf

Error message: The type 'GoogleMapProject_Behaviors:ZoomBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

Here is the code:

> ```
> <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
>     <GoogleMapProject_Behaviors:ZoomBehavior/>
>     <GoogleMapProject_Behaviors:PanBehavior 
>         RightHandPosition="{Binding RightHandPosition, Mode=TwoWay}" 
>         LeftHandPosition="{Binding LeftHandPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
>         IsPanning="{Binding IsPanning, Mode=TwoWay}">
>         </GoogleMapProject_Behaviors:PanBehavior> 
> </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your namespace, which is mapped in your XAML as `GoogleMapProject_Behaviors` does not contain a class `ZoomBehavior`.

- Check the Namespace mapping (at the top of your XAML file): Does
  `GoogleMapProject_Behaviors` refer to the correct namespace?
- Next, check your class `ZoomBehavior`: Is the namespace defined
  correspondingly, Is the class Public, does it have a default
  constructor?

The fact that VS complains about the class indicates that the namespace can be resolved, so that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sebastian! I've checked the namespace mapping, and the class ZoomBehavior as well but there is nothing wrong..